# Radiobutton dynamically

Tags: android

I have a edittext depending on the number given in edit text i have to create a radiobutton but im getting error this is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        go=(Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
        no=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.noofradio);
        err=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.err);
        go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               try
               {
                   int a = Integer.parseInt(no.getText().toString());
                   RadioGroup radiogroup = new RadioGroup(MainActivity.this);
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams rg = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                           RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                           RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                       radiobutton = new RadioButton(MainActivity.this);
                       radiobutton.setText(i);
                       radiobutton.setId(i);
                       radiogroup.addView(radiobutton, rg);


                   }
               }
               catch(Exception ex)
               {
                   err.setText(ex.toString());
               }
            }
        });


    }

}
```

this is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >"
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButtons"
        android:id="@+id/err"/>
      <EditText
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text=""
           android:id="@+id/noofradio">
       </EditText>
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/go"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Buttons">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: cAN U PLS elaborate whr u getting error and what error?pls paste logcat o/p here

Comment: android content resource$not found exception stringresource id ..i dont know how to use logcat

Comment: at looking ur erro ithink u have not declare ids for ur views in xml.pls paste xml file here for more review

Answer (score 1):

> android content resource$not found exception stringresource id

I think you have an error in your xml (well, using undefined string resource, I guess)

Comment: You could post your layout file (main.xml), and values/strings.xml would be helpful too

Comment: It doesn't really look like an xml :)

Comment: i have posted it but its not appearing ??

Comment: It is now. Don't see anything wrong (exept " after >, code highlighting error?)...

Answer (score 0):

The call to setText() is expecting a string resource id.  Specifically, `radiobutton.setText(i)` is interpreting 'i' to be a string resource id vs. the index you are passing in.